# Wordpress - add anchor links for title in wp_list_pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok so I'm listing out my pages in my bootstrap menu thus

```
<?php wp_list_pages(array(
                      'title_li' => '', 
                      'link_after' => '<?php get_page_link($id); ?>', 
                      'exclude'      => '35, 215, 121, 5')); ?>
```

but what I want is to do is use the title_li such as 'contact' as an anchor at the end of the link for use on another page where I'm setting a div id as the page title so I jump straight down to that div on the new page.

Answer (score 0):

write echo on link then it work.

```
<?php wp_list_pages(array(
                  'title_li' => '', 
                  'link_after' => '<?php echo get_page_link($id); ?>', 
                  'exclude'      => '35, 215, 121, 5')); ?>
```

and you can also try this one

```
<?php wp_list_pages(array(
                  'title_li' => '', 
                  'link_after' => '<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>', 
                  'exclude'      => '35, 215, 121, 5')); ?>
```